# How can I add consecutive numbers to the front of my lines of text using C# and/or Notepad++?

Tags: c#, notepad++

I basically have a whole list of data that looks like this:

```
text', 0, 16, 0, 160),
text text', 0, 36, 0, 720),
text text text', 6, 14, 200, 400),
text text', 6, 20, 40, 185),
text text text text', 6, 6, 80, 80),
text text', 0, 18, 0, 260),
text text text', 3, 3, 60, 60),
```

I need this to look like this:

```
(1444, text text', 0, 36, 0, 720),
(1445, text text text', 6, 14, 200, 400),
(1446, text text', 6, 20, 40, 185),
(1447, text text text text', 6, 6, 80, 80),
(1448, text text', 0, 18, 0, 260),
(1449, text text text', 3, 3, 60, 60),
```

So I basically wrote a for loop in C# to generate the numbers:

```
 for(int i =0; i < amount; i ++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("("+counter+",");
            counter++;
        }
```

Counter being the numbers I need and amount being the amount of times I need numbers generated.

I am trying to figure out how to get "(1111," in front of "text', 0, 0, 0, 0)," per each line, I was trying to find and replace in notepad but I couldn't get it to work, is there a way I could do the whole thing in C#? Or any other way at all?

Comment: Are you just trying to output like that?  Or actually modify the file?

Comment: It's not clear. Do you have a "txt" file and whant to replace all lines? Do you want to add an starting brace and the consecutive number?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, I am just trying to modify my file to add the starting brace and numbers in front of each line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just use Excel or other spreadsheet processor?

Comment: It turns out to be the easiest way! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
var indexedLines = yourData.Select((line, idx) => new {Line = line, Index = idx});

foreach(var indexedLine in indexedLines)
    Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1}", indexedLine.Index, indexedLine.Line);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the following resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx

And try doing something like:

```
Console.Writeline("(" + counter + "," + line);
```